# LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy adds nodes from datacenters other than local_dc also

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

In the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.4.1/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.html) of LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy, it's mentioned that -

> Selects local node first and then nodes in local DC in random order. Never selects nodes from other DCs. For writes, if a statement has a routing key set, this LBP is token aware - it prefers the nodes which are replicas of the computed token to the other nodes.

However in my spark jobs logs I can find all the Nodes is cluster being added.

```
21/05/05 10:08:40 INFO CassandraWriter$: Setting local_dc: DC1
21/05/05 10:08:40 INFO CassandraWriter$: Writing to DC: DC1, available host ips: x.x.x.54,x.x.x.237,x.x.x.168,x.x.x.197,x.x.x.219
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /x.x.x.219:9042 added
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /x.x.x.237:9042 added
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /x.x.x.54:9042 added
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /x.x.x.238:9042 added
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host x.x.x.238 (DC2)
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /x.x.x.168:9042 added
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /x.x.x.42:9042 added
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host x.x.x.42 (DC2)
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /x.x.x.109:9042 added
21/05/05 10:08:41 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host x.x.x.109 (DC2)
```

Could somebody help me understand **why DC2 nodes are being added? As per my understanding, coordinator nodes are always chosen from local_dc.**

I have tried to run ingestion without setting spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc as well and have seen the same logs.

See write code below:

```
records.write.cassandraFormat(table, keySpace)
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .option(CassandraConnectorConf.LocalDCParam.name, cassandraDC.name)
  .option(CassandraConnectorConf.ConnectionHostParam.name, cassandraDC.availableHosts.mkString(","))
  .save()
```

PS: I have separate spark and cassandra clusters & my use-case is to write data from spark cluster to cassandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore these messages. This is how the Cassandra works - drivers are discovering the full topology of the cluster on initialization, and then deciding to use only specific nodes from given datacenter.

For example, messages like `New Cassandra host /x.x.x.54:9042 added` are [coming from Java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.java#L1782).  And messages like `Added host x.x.x.238 (DC2)` are [coming from LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.4/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala#L76) that must override the function in the interface.  But then, load balancing policy [doesn't use the nodes that aren't in the local data center](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.4/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala#L122), although always keeps a map of all nodes.

Comment: Thanks, that for the perfect answer, clears a lot of confusion for me!